# O(n^c) ~= O(n*log n), Which value has c?

Tags: algorithm, math, complexity-theory, asymptotic-complexity

I wonder, how low must be the exponent of `n` to become less complex than `n*log(n)` (in other words, the `n^c`? Asymptote to `n * log(n, 2)`, how low `c` must be in a `n^c` algorithm to be *less efficient* than a `n log n` algorithm ). I have seeing that it is *+- above* `1.10`, but I want to know how to figure it out.

I tryied and I suck at math and I would like to have an *mathematical explanation* to it. Thanks!

Comment: For high n, `n*log(n)` is growing slower than any `n^c` (assuming of course that you mean n to the power of c). On the other hand, `n*log(n)` is growing faster than n. So I think your equation cannot be solved; not even inside O() discussion, which glosses over most differences in factors and offsets.

Comment: c = log[base n] (n*log(n))

Comment: shit, right, i feel very stupid now, hahaha. Thanks, really.

Comment: @robertking this `c` is not constant.

Comment: Seems, what you really wanted to ask is for which constants `c` is `n^c` in `O(n log n)`. And the answer is for `c <= 1`.

Answer (score 5):

If `~=` means *equivalent* then

```
 O(n^c) ~= O(n*log(n))
```

means

```
 lim ((n^c) / (n * log(n)) = const <> 0
   n -> +inf
```

Please, notice that `log2(n) = logK(n) / logK(2)` where `1 / logK(2)` is a *constant factor*; that's why `O(n*log2(n)) == O(n*logK(n))` and we can choose *any base* `K` we like. It's covenient to work with *natural logarithms* (`K = e`).

Let's find out the corresponding `c` when the limit above is a *non-zero* `const` (actually, `const` is a positive value):

```
 lim ((n^c) / (n * log(n)) = lim n^(c - 1) / log(n) = 
   n -> +inf                   n -> +inf
```

Now let's use [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule). 
Providing that `c <> 0` (in this exceptional case the derivative of `d(n^(c - 1))/dn = d(n^-1)/dn = log(n)`)

```
 lim (c - 1) * n^(c - 2) / (1 / n) = lim (c - 1) * n^(c - 1) = (c - 1) * lim n^(c - 1) = 
   n -> +inf                           n -> +inf                           n -> +inf
```

And the limit `lim n^(c - 1)` is

```
        0 if c < 1
    const if c = 1 <- we want this case
     +inf if c > 1
```

So we want `c = 1` case and finally we have

```
    (c - 1) * lim n^(c - 1) = /* c = 1 */ = (1 - 1) * const = 0
                n -> + inf
```

Alas! **there's no such** `c` that `O(n^c) ~= O(n*log(n))` holds. We have

```
    O(n^c) < O(n*log(n)) // when c <= 1
    O(n^c) > O(n*log(n)) // when c > 1
```

Please, notice that there's no such `c` when `O(n^c) ~= O(n*log(n))`...